# Rebind error in gwt-cal widget DayViewStyleManager

Tags: java, gwt

Maybe somebody have also been working with gwt-cal widget that emulates Google Calendar and iCal for GWT.I have started recently, but when I tried a simple calendar into my project, such as:

```
public class ManagerCalendarViewImpl extends Composite implements
ManagerCalendarView {

SimplePanel viewPanel = new SimplePanel();

public ManagerCalendarViewImpl() {
    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.setDate(new Date());
    calendar.setDays(3);
    calendar.setWidth("500px");
    calendar.setHeight("400px");
    viewPanel.add(calendar);
} 
}
```

I got the following errors when to perform GWT compile:

```
  Errors in 
 jar:file:/D:/Naukma/Programing/JavaEE/GWT_Projects/CalendarMVP/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-cal-0.9.3.jar!/com/bradrydzewski/gwt/calendar/client/dayview/DayView.java
[ERROR] Line 58:  Rebind result com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.client.dayview.DayViewStyleManager' cannot be abstract
[ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/Naukma/Programing/JavaEE/GWT_Projects/CalendarMVP/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/gwt- cal-0.9.3.jar!/com/bradrydzewski/gwt/calendar/client/monthview/MonthView.java'
[ERROR] Line 154:  Rebind result 'com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.client.monthview.MonthViewStyleManager' cannot be abstract
[ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
```

I haven't changed any part of code inside jars. According to their wiki , this settings are not required. Firstly, errors began to appear when I had DayView set, but even when I modified code like above, they didn't disappear.I cleaned the project, tried to compile and got the same. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry to bother, simply forgot to inherit a module, but thought it has been inherited.